# Confusion regarding permissions needed to implement In-App purchase in my android app

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

I am trying to implement In App Purchase in my android app that I am making with flutter. What I want to ask is that do I need to add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml, **`"<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>"`**. I have this confusion because I released app bundle after adding this permission and the GP Console is giving me this error **"We've detected this app uses an unsupported version of Play billing. Please upgrade to Billing Library version 5 or newer to publish this app."** If that permission is not required then do I need some other permissions or implementations?

Comment: That permission is required for allowing In-App Purchase in your app. The library or the implementation you are trying is probably using an older version of Billing Library which isn't supported anymore in favour of Billing 5.x.

Comment: @Darshan How do I upgrade my Billing Library version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upgrade billing library in build.gradle for (Module:app) like this:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
}
```

6.0 is the latest version of billing library.